# Issues with code when upgrading to Lucene .net 4.8.0-beta0004

Tags: lucene.net

I upgraded Lucene.net in my C sharp application from 3.0.3 to 4.8.0-beta0004 and I also installed the last version of Lucene.net.analysis.common and Lucene.net.queries.

Several lines in my code are throwing errors:

Error 1:)
    Analyzer standAnalyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);

The error is : The type or the namespace name "StandardAnalyzer" could not be found.

Error 2)
Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser parser = new Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, "Content", standAnalyzer);

The error is: The type or the namespace name "QueryParsers" does not exist in the namespace 'Lucene.Net'

Error 3)
 Lucene.Net.Search.Searcher schr = new Lucene.Net.Search.IndexSearcher(Lucene.Net.Index.IndexReader.Open(directory, true));

The error is : The type or the namespace name "Searcher" does not exist in the namespace 'Lucene.Net.Search'

I'm using the following namaspace in my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Lucene.Net.Analysis;
using Lucene.Net.Index;
using Lucene.Net.Search;
using Lucene.Net.Search.Spans;
```

Could be please help? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The project structure of Lucene changed greatly from 3.x to 4.x and increased in size by more than a factor of 10. As a result, many of the classes are no longer in the same Namespace as they were previously.

1. StandardAnalyzer - add `using Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard`.
2. QueryParser - add `using Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.Classic`. Note there are now many other types of QueryParsers available.
3. IndexSearcher - there is no longer an abstract `Searcher` base class. The simplest way to fix this would be to change the line to: `var schr = new Lucene.Net.Search.IndexSearcher(Lucene.Net.Index.IndexReader.Open(directory, true));`

For future reference, you can view the [Lucene 4.8.0 API doucmentation (in Java)](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_0/) to see how the project structure has changed. Lucene.Net followed this structure very closely.

Also, using Visual Studio 2015 or higher, there is a nice feature that allows you do automatically add the `using` statements based on the class name. You just need to hover over the type that is underlined in red, and click on the little light bulb dropdown.

[image]

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The most recent prerelease version, which is now `4.8.0-beta00008`, has no Lucene.Net.Analysis.Common in the main NuGet package (i.e. previous answer with `using Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard` will not work). The namespace can be installed additionally as

```
Install-Package Lucene.Net -Version 4.8.0-beta00008 
Install-Package Lucene.Net.Analysis.Common -Version 4.8.0-beta00008
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Lucene.Net.Analysis.Common/